# Flow of ODE with monotone source

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Phi$ be the flow (defined as in page 6 of [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/JEDP_2004____A1_0.pdf)) of the ODE
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(x,t) = f(\Phi(x,t),t) \quad t >0 \\
\Phi(x,0) = x \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{cases}$$

> Is it true that if $f$ is monotone in the first variable then $\Phi$ is Lipschitz?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose  that $f$ is decreasing in $x$. Let $x(t)$, $y(t)$ be two solutions of the ode.  Then
$$
\dot{x}-\dot{y}= f(x,t)-f(y,t).
$$

Multiplying both sides by $x-y$ we deduce

$$
(\dot{x}-\dot{y})(x-y) =\big(f(x,t)-f(y,t)\big)(x-y)\leq 0,
$$ 
where the last equality holds because $f$ is decreasing.

Hence
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\big(x-y)^2\leq 0.
$$
Thus the function $t\mapsto \big( x(t)-y(t)\big)^2 $ is decreasing so
$$
\big(x(t)-y(t)\big)^2\leq \big( x(0)-y(0)\big)^2,\;\;\forall t\geq 0,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\Big(\Phi(x_0,t)-\Phi(y_0,t)\Big)^2\leq \Big(x_0-y_0\Big)^2,\;\;\forall t\geq 0.
$$
In other words, for $t\geq 0$, $\Phi(x,t)$ is Lipschitz  in $x$ with Lipschitz constant $1$ if $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: Thank you. How can the argument be made rigorous even when $f$ is not smooth and $\Phi$ is not a classical solution but a regular Lagrangian flow?

Comment: The function $f$  coud even be  multivalued, and you  can work in an infinite dimensional  Hilbert space as well  This  is a special case  of the  general theory of maximal monotone operators and the associated differential equations.    Perhaps the friendliest introduction is Brezis' book  *Operateurs maximaux monotones et semi-groupes de contractions dans les espaces de Hilbert*.    The ultimate reference is  however V. Barbu's book  *Nonlinear semigroups and differen tial equations in Banach spaces*

Comment: The finite dimensional case is discussed  in V. Barbu's recent book  *Differential Equations*  Springer 2016, Example 2.4 and Sec. 2.7.

Comment: In the scalar case all you need for existence and uniqueness is that  $f$ is decreasing and the function $\mathbb{R}\ni x\mapsto f(x)-x\in\mathbb{R}$ is onto.

Comment: Thank you. What if $f$ is increasing?

Comment: Look at the initial value problem $\dot{x}=\sqrt{x}$, $x(0)=1$ and see what happens.

Comment: I see, but we can still recover Lipschitz continuity if we work on a bounded time interval $[0,T]$. In general, can we prove that the flow exists is unique and Lipschitz if we consider $t \in [0,T]$ and assume $f$ increasing but not regular?

Comment: You  forget that  the blow-up time depends on the initial condition. Also uniqueness  could be lost.

Comment: Take the initial value problem  $\dot{x}=x^{1/3}$, $x(0)=0$. It has *two* solutions $x(t)=0$ and $x(t)=(2t/3)^{3/2}$. For $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is not defined for $t>0$. It is well defined for $t<0$ because $-x^{1/3}$ is as you know *decreasing*.